# create json representation for decimal logical type and byte types for avro schema

Tags: scala, avro, event-bus, avro-tools

I am trying to create JSON string as per below avro schema, for decimal value.
https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/spec.html#Logical+Types

```
{
 "name": "score",
 "type": "bytes",
 "logicalType": "decimal",
 "precision": 10,
 "scale": 5
 }
```

value

```
"score":3.4,
```

I am getting exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected bytes. Got VALUE_NUMBER_FLOAT.
```

Instead of 3.4 if I give "\u0000" then it works but this is representation of 0, how I will get representation for 3.4?
For now I am creating hard-coded JSON String, but in future I have to convert output into Decimal, how I can do that in scala.

Is there any way to convert value into decimal logical format?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am facing a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60623764/creating-sample-avro-data-for-bytes-type

Comment: yes, unfortunately I don't have that code with me. I converted value into byte format, just look for converting float into byte format and I think it should work.

Comment: if you could find that code that would be amazing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java code:

```
byte[] score = new BigDecimal("3.40000").unscaledValue().tobyteArray();
for (byte b : score) {​
    System.out.println(String.format("\\u%04x", b));
}
```

Will print out following:

```
\u00fa
\u00cf
\u00e0
```

You then need to write json score value like this:

```
"score":"\u00fa\u00cf\u00e0",
```

And it should translate to 3.40000.
The reason why 3.**40000** is because 'scale' in your schema has value 5. If scale would have value 2, then we would have new BigDecimal("3.40")

Scala function for converting BigDecimal to json so avro will understand it

```
def toJsonString(value: java.math.BigDecimal): String = {
    val bytes = value.unscaledValue().toByteArray
    bytes
      .map(_.formatted("\\u%04x"))
      .mkString
}
```