# Creating sample Avro data for bytes type

Tags: json, hive, schema, avro, avro-tools

I am trying to create a sample `.avro` file containing `bytes` as type and `decimal` as logicalType, But the `avro` file when loaded to hive table results in a different value. What could be the reason?

schema.avsc:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "example",
  "namespace" : "com.xyz.avro",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "cost",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "bytes",
      "logicalType" : "decimal",
      "precision" : 38,
      "scale" : 10
    }
  }]
}
```

data.json:

```
{ "cost" : "0.0" }
```

Converted to `.avro` using `avro-tools`:

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.8.2.jar fromjson --schema-file schema.avsc data.json > data.avro
```

After loading `data.avro` and querying the hive table:

```
hive> select cost from tmp_cost;
OK
0.0003157552
```

A similar question on SO: [create json representation for decimal logical type and byte types for avro schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57995567/create-json-representation-for-decimal-logical-type-and-byte-types-for-avro-sche)

Comment: Did you figure out the reason?